# Recursively source files to environment

Tags: r

I want to run a function in a folder in a completely isolated environment. This function has some resources that it refers to, also in this folder.

I know how to load R functions into a new environment using `source()`:

```
ne <- new.env()
source("myFuncs.R", ne)
```

However, if `myFuncs.R` contains `source()` calls itself in the form `source("helpers.R")`, these functions are loaded into the global environment!

How can I *recursively source* files into a new environment? Can this be done in `R` without having to somehow hack my way around this with regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redefine `source`:

```
ne <- new.env()
source <- function(file, local = ne, ...) base::source(file, local, ...)

source("myFuncs.R")

rm(source)
```